# Unable to UPDATE row, only INSERT to my MySQL table. Syntax Error "WHERE ID =0"

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

I'm having a few issues as I'm new to MySQL and a PHP novice. On submissions of my form if I use the INSERT command it works fine. If I change the command to UPDATE, it can't find the 'ID' to update. I've replaced the WHERE ID with the exact row ID but comes back with sytax error.

Heres my code to add:

```
function create()
{
    $sql = sprintf(
        "INSERT minty_config 
        (name, value) 
        VALUES
        ('%s','%s')",
        $this->db->clean($this->name),
        $this->db->clean($this->value)
    );

    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

Here's my code to update:

```
function update()
{
    $sql = sprintf(
        "UPDATE minty_config  SET
        name='%s', 
        value='%s', 
        WHERE ID=%d",
        $this->db->clean($this->name),
        $this->db->clean($this->value),
        $this->ID
    );

    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

I'm guessing I need to change the following php so I can UPDATE instead of INSERT but everytime I try to make changes I just get a blank screen so something is wrong. This is the code:

```
    session_start();
    // Connection to server established here//
    include('../config.php');
    // Authentication of login here//
    if (!$user->authenticated)
    {
        header('Location: login.php');
        die();
    }
    //'text' is class where I have list of functions: get, set, update, create, etc. //
    if (isset($post->form_action))
    {
        $a = new text(false, $db);
        $a->name = $post->name;
        $a->value = $post->value;
    //this function works if use 'create' but when changed to 'update I get a Syntax error //   
        if (!$err)
        {
            $a->update();
            $succ = "Success!";
        }
    }
```

I've tried something like this to fix this WHERE ID syntax error but it returns a blank screen and I can't even see the form:

```
    $id = (isset($get->id) && is_numeric($get->id)) ? $get->id : ((isset($post->id) && is_numeric($post->id)) ? $post->id : false);
    if (!$id) die();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't know which coding style you are using but try this: in update query remove comma after value='%s', and tell me is it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your update query has an extra **,** comma before where

```
"UPDATE minty_config  SET name='%s', value='%s', WHERE ID=%d"
                                              ^^^
```

It should be

```
"UPDATE minty_config  SET name='%s', value='%s' WHERE ID=%d"
                                              ^^
```

I've just removed that extra comma. This'll work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your code is throwing an error somewhere.   Set error_reporting(E_ALL) and see if anything comes up.

echo your query before you execute it and run it on the SQL server, does it work?

If it works, step through your code using debugger (or just use echo/print_r statements as breakpoints).

You said you were getting an error, what is it?

Post any info you find in your question and I can probably help more if you still need it.